# Xamarin Component throws System.NotSupportedException while creating a .xam package

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-component

I am trying to upload a Xamarin Component by using xamarin-component.exe tool as written in [this guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/submitting_components/component_submission_guide/). While it is building the `.xam` package file, the command console is throwing the following error:

[image: xamarin-component.exe forcefully closing after this error popup]

What is the problem? I am running it on windows. Is this related to machine permission?

Comment: What is the path in which your directory resides? There may be some unexpected characters. Please add it to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reason for the error message.The file paths format I've given for build,libraries,samples in the component.yaml file was not in the specified format. Also the spaces between the build,libraries,samples's keys and their respective values should be maintained as per the component submission guide.Like this,  build:
  - src/samplecomponent.sln
libraries:
  ios-unified: ../src/samplecomponent/bin/release/Awesome.dll